# Vaadin SQLContainer Strange Behaviour

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, vaadin, vaadin7

I am experiencing some issues with SQLContainer from Vaadin. The name of my SQLContainer is agentContainer.

Now if I run the following code:

```
System.out.println(agentContainer.getItemIds());
System.out.println(agentContainer.containsId("3"));
System.out.println(agentContainer.containsId(new RowId(new Object[]{"3"})));
System.out.println(agentContainer.getItem((new RowId(new Object[]{"3"}))));
System.out.println(agentContainer.getItem("3"));
```

I get:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 13, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,
>   26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,
>   43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]
>
> false
>
> true
>
> null
>
> null

I am completely lost as to why the `contains` returns true but the `getItem` returns null.

Can anyone help me identify why this is happening?

Comment: Is the key field a number? It looks to me like integers. TrySystem.out.println(agentContainer.getItem(3))

Comment: You are correct. That resolved the issue. Although we can put generic objects in there its sensitive to the the underlying field type.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the getItem can be given any object you like but the object type must match the underlying field. For for number provider Integer and for String types provide String.